# Detecting collision between 2 rotated rectangles with limited parameters

Tags: collision-detection, javascript

Are there any function that can detect collisions between 2 rotated rectangles in javascript with this kind of information:

```
r1 = {x:0,y:0,w:2,h:2,transformX:5,transformY:Y,rot:30}
r2 = {x:1,y:1,w:2,h:2,transformX:5,transformY:Y,rot:30}
//rot is degrees
function rectColliding(rect1,rect2){
  //Code
}

console.log(rectColliding(r1,r2))
```

Comment: Google "2D OBB Intersection". OBB is Oriented Bounding Box which is an arbitrarily rotated rectangle.

Comment: I get x, y, w, and h, but what does transformX and transformY mean?

Comment: @mackycheese21 The origin of rotation. I'm using Javascript Transform and rotate, dont forget.

Comment: @user2927848 I've seen that before, and I would very much liek to try it, but I dont know how to gte the vertecies of a roated angle.

Comment: Then search/ask [how to get the vertices after rotating by that angle](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/86755/39518). This is just highschool math, not an insurmountable barrier.

Comment: @DMGregory I never said I'm in high school yet...

Comment: That's fine, Google doesn't do an age check on searching, and neither does our own site's search box. ;) Use all the tools available to you and you'll solve problems faster.

Comment: Using google would help to find the informations needed..

Answer (score 0):

Since you get no answers I will try to help. 
I am not super proficient in math etc, but your best approach would be to check if one or more of the vertices of one of the rectangles are inside the other rectangle BUT not all of them obviously.

So you will have to map your rects vertices taking the angle in to consideration... and then use a raycast/raytrace algorithm to determine if the vertices are inside other rect.

I hope this overview will get you started:
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ray_casting

Comment: The only issue I have with this is I'm not proficient in Javascript. I don't know how to implement that. I don't know how to get the vertecies either.